# How to remove beeping sound in dev mode in chrome-os?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

How would I remove the beeping loud annoying sound when entering developer mode in Chrome OS? Is there a terminal command to remove this?

Answer (score 4):

> **[Neutering the “developer mode” screen on your Chromebook](https://johnlewis.ie/neutering-the-developer-mode-screen-on-your-chromebook/)**
>
> Having to press CTRL + D at every boot, or wait 30 seconds and endure
>   a loud, audible beep is not my idea of slick fun. Happily, it is
>   possible to all but disable this screen, by rewriting the BIOS with
>   the correct “flags”. This leaves the screen enabled, but it only
>   displays for 2 seconds, and there is no beep. Unhappily, you have to
>   physically open the Chromebook up and disable the inbuilt BIOS write
>   protect to take advantage of this.
>
> The procedure is a follows:
>
> - Open Chromebook and enable/disable write protect jumper
> - Read existing BIOS using flashrom
> - Write new BIOS file with correct flags using gbb_utility
> - Write new BIOS file to BIOS using flashrom

Comment: This is rather a long process but i will check on it !